# Finding Lebesgue outer measure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $f:[0,2)\to \mathbb R$ be defined by

$f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{cc}
  x^2  & \mbox{if } 0\le x \le 1 \\
  3-x & \mbox{if } 1<x <2
 \end{array}
\right.$

Find $m^*(A)$, where $A=f^{-1}(\dfrac{9}{16},\dfrac{5}{4})$ and $m^*$ denotes the Lebesgue outer measure.

I tried to solve the problem as follows:

Since, $A=f^{-1}(\dfrac{9}{16},\dfrac{5}{4})=(\dfrac{3}{4},1]\cup (\dfrac{7}{4},2)$, thus $m^*(A)\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$. But I could not establish the reverse inequality. Please help!

Comment: Do you know that the Lebesgue measure of an open interval is the length of the interval? If so, $A = (3/4, 1) \cup(7/4, 2) \cup \{1,2\}$.

Comment: Lebesgue measure is finitely subadditive, so $m^*(A)\leq \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It should be outer measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the only thing is to recognize that $A = (\frac 34, 1] \bigcup (\frac 74, 2] \in \mathscr{L}$, where $\mathscr{L}$ denotes the collection of Lebesgue measurable sets. On $\mathscr{L}$, $m^{*}$ actually equals to $m$. So $m^{*}(A) = m(A) = \frac 12$.

Comment: $2\notin [0,2)$